# install Apache ActiveMQ directly in Apache Karaf

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-karaf

I am trying to install Apache ActiveMQ directly in Apache Karaf as per [this](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/jms.html) link.

- step 1: `karaf@root()> feature:install jms`
- step 2: `karaf@root()> feature:repo-add activemq`

step 1& 2 sucessfully executed

- step 3: `karaf@root()> feature:install activemq-broker`

step 3 shows the following error:

```
Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi
.identity; osgi.identity=camel-jms; type=karaf.feature; version="[2.15.0,3.0.0)"
```

I am using apache karaf 4.0.0 m2 and apache activemq 5.9.0, please help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work as per Karaf 4.0 the API provided is Servlet 3.1. 
So you need to use a newer version of ActiveMQ a snapshot most likely. 
AFAIK this issue has already been addressed at the Karaf user mailinglist.

Comment: Hi     I changed activemq5.11.1.      But no use. same pbm still remains. I  adding my steps..                                                                                                   1.  feature:repo-add activemq 5.11.1                                                                   2.  feature:install activemq-broker.                                                      Error:Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi
.identity; osgi.identity=activemq-web-console; type=karaf.feature; version=5.11.

Comment: You need to use the latest 5.12.0-SNAPSHOT version, it's the one with the corrected import range.

Comment: Again the same pbm.                                                                                 Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi
.identity; osgi.identity=activemq-web-console; type=karaf.feature; version=5.12.
0.SNAPSHOT [caused by: Unable to resolve activemq-web-console/5.12.0.SNAPSHOT: m
issing requirement [activemq-web-console/5.12.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.id
entity=org.apache.activemq.activemq-web-console; type=osgi.bundle; version="[5.1
2.0.SNAPSHOT,5.12.0.SNAPSHOT]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to reso

Comment: I think you already got an answer at the karaf mailinglist. It's due to an issue of the webconsole which is already being addressed.

Answer (score 0):

The current and quick solution for this is to execute with Karaf 3.x. I got this working with Karaf 3.0.3. If you can downgrade Karaf, you may also have Karaf 3.x and install ActiveMQ features in it.